# Selecting odd child DIV inside another div

Tags: html, css

I have one main `div` (with class catpopular) and four nested `div`'s (with class item). I need to select only odd nested `div`'s in `CSS`. Please note that there are also `div`'s inside nested `div`'s but css should ignore that. The html is -

```
<div class="catpopular">
   <div class="item">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <div>content</div>
   </div>

   <div class="item">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <div>content</div>
   </div>

   <div class="item">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <div>content</div>
   </div>

   <div class="item">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <div>content</div>
   </div>

   <div class="item">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <div>content</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The css is tried -

```
.catpopular .item:nth-child(odd){

}
```

But it is not working. Please help

Comment: your css looks right, what styles are you applying?

Comment: `margin-left:0px` Please not that using bootstrap `span`  in the divs , so that 20px margin is automatically added. I only need margin for the even child not odd child.

Comment: I'm thinking that your style is likely being applied, but isn't working for some other reason.. try setting `color:blue` or something more obvious

Comment: ow. changing `odd` to `even` made it worked. But how come is that? :/

Comment: CSS selector is correct. But you need to fix HTML: `<div>content<div>` - note unclosed divs.

Comment: Sorry for example above. It was typo, my actual code is little bit different. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you didn't close your div-tags correctly. 
To select all the odd items, you can use following css-code as in your example, so your css code was right !!

```
.catpopular .item:nth-child(odd) {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

I made a jsfiddle as well to illustrate: https://jsfiddle.net/78kxk7ds/

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, I'm happy that I could solve your problem ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the div tags correctly - it should be

```
<div class="item">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <div>content</div>
</div>
```

You are missing the "/" from the closing  tag.

Comment: Sorry for example above. It was typo, my actual code is little bit different. Thanks btw.